# The header image is closing up when mobile screen

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a webpage for my [own business](http://crossfit24.mx). I chose Bootstrap because it comes mobile-capable out of the box. I'm having a problem:

- When accessing the webpage using a phone (iPhone 5) the header image does a close up, zooming in with no proportions.

Here is the code:

```
#heading {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 543px;     
  background: url('../images/header.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -4px 9px -3px #000;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -4px 9px -3px #000;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -4px 9px -3px #000;
}

@media(max-width:563px) {
  #heading {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;         
    background: url('../images/headerm.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
  }
  #navigation .navlinks li {
    margin-right: 1px;
  }
  #navigation .navlinks li a {
    padding: 0 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
  }

}
```

I tried using a different size image for the media query, but it didn't work.

[Here](http://crossfit24.mx/test) is the link for testing scenario. If you shrinks your browser to simulate phone screen, the image doesn't do the close up. It has to be on a phone.

Comment: this would make you go a little further: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559764/background-image-scaling-while-maintaining-aspect-ratio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@media(max-width:563px) {
  #heading {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;         
    background: url('../images/headerm.jpg') no-repeat center center scroll; 
    -webkit-background-size: 100% auto;
    -moz-background-size: 100% auto;
    -o-background-size: 100% auto;
    background-size: 100% auto;
  }
}
```

Should work. Change fixed to scroll.

Comment: Is it possible the image fits the width automatically? It is not closing up anymore, but it doesn't fit the screen. May be changing the image size again ? You can take a look now to the [test link](http://www.crossfit24.mx/test) to see the modified version.