# Background-size:contain "y"?

Tags: javascript, css, html, background

Is there a way of making a background fit a div "height" while keeping his ratio ? Like a contain but for "y" only ? according to this answer there isn't [Background Image Scaling While Maintaining Aspect Ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559764/background-image-scaling-while-maintaining-aspect-ratio) however considering that the most voted answer quoted some css3 possiblities I was wondering if there was a way nowdays to do so in css3 or maybe javascript ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just set the height to `100%` and the width to `auto`:

```css
.foo {
    background-size: auto 100%;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but he want to other way around, height 100% width auto.

Comment: So swap the values; am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do it:

```
.myDiv { background-size: cover; }
```

See the details here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp