# How to scale an image to cover entire parent div?

Tags: javascript, html, image, css

http://jsfiddle.net/Log82brL/15/

This `<img>` isn't shrink wrapping as I would expect with `min-width:100%`

I'm trying to shrink the  `<img>` until either height or width matches the container

Click anywhere in the `<iframe>` to toggle container shapes

Please try to edit the `<img>` CSS:

1. MAINTAIN ASPECT RATIO
2. COVER ENTIRE SURFACE AREA OF CONTAINER DIV
3. **ONLY EDIT THE IMAGE**

My question is specifically: scale an `<img>` to maintain aspect ratio but cover the entire surface of parent `<div>` even as the parent `<div>` resizes.

Maybe I could somehow use css flex box-layout or something? Maybe a transform?

Comment: Can you add a fiddle or pen of the same?

Comment: Did you try adding width and height attr to the img tag and set it to auto or inherit?

Comment: How can it maintain aspect ration and still cover entire surface. I don't get it.

Comment: Do you want the equivalent of `background-size: cover` but for an img element? If not, like @Riddler, I don't understand either what you want to achieve

Comment: maybe you should upload an image of exactly how you want the image to look in the 2 views using something like photoshop?

Comment: If you use background image as opposed to an `<img>`, you can use this trick: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559764/background-image-scaling-while-maintaining-aspect-ratio

Answer (score 38, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Log82brL/7/

```
#img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

object-fit: cover allows the replaced content is sized to maintain its aspect ratio while filling the element’s entire content box: its concrete object size is resolved as a cover constraint against the element’s used width and height.

Comment: This method has terrible [browser support](http://caniuse.com/object-fit), but there's a [polyfill](https://github.com/anselmh/object-fit) for that.

Comment: The support is not that bad at all. It is only IE that doesn't support it. http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit

Comment: As much as I wish it weren't so, IE still makes up a good portion of browser usage.  Still, this is the same answer I would have given, so I can't complain too much.  I mostly just wanted to mention the polyfill.

Comment: target usecase is webkit browsers, i fortunately dont have to deal with IE, i think this might be the real answer, i just can't get it to work with the fiddle

Comment: oh man, thanks! this saved me after hours of pulling my hair out.

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question. The accepted answer is a hack and goes against the semantic html.

Comment: is there any easy way to center the image? it seems to be left-aligned

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want to touch the container, put the background on the `<img>`

```
#img { 
  background: url(imgpath) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

You can set HTML source to a transparent base64 pixel (credit [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/base64-encode-of-1x1px-transparent-gif/))

```
<img id="img" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Log82brL/17/

Comment: wow, how did nobody think of this. i can't touch the container div because it's a shared class, but the img can definitely have an empty source

Comment: This is a hack and goes against the semantic html. `object-fit: cover; width: 100%; height: 100%` is the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

Did u try the bootstrap solution

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images-responsive

which is pretty much

```
.img-responsive
{
max-width: 100%;
height: auto; 
display: block;
}
```

Adding to your update question

http://jsfiddle.net/arunzo/Log82brL/5/

```
.skinny>img
{
    max-width:none !important;
    min-height:none !important;    
    max-height:100%;
    -webkit-transform:translate3d(+50%, +50%, 0);
}
```

And still i am unsure what is that you seek, sorry for the jerky animation.

Comment: width cannot ever be less than 100% if i want it to fill the entire surface. i believe your solution fits the image within the container

Comment: i only want to have the top/bottom outside of the parent, or left/right outside of the parent, but not both, and it needs to stretch if the parent container grows

Comment: I understand and that is exactly what i have achieved. Try using chrome inspector tools to verify it yourself. Resize the Result window just in case

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS `background` instead of HTML `img`.

```
.myDiv
{
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  background-image: url('image-url.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center center;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

<div class="myDiv">
</div>
```

Here is the [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fdvj9c1n/1/).
Try to change `height` and `width` - you will see that image stretches to fill the `div`.

You can also different `background-size` values:

1. Proportional stretch to contain: `background-size: contain;`
   [Too tall div](http://jsfiddle.net/fdvj9c1n/1/)
   [Too wide div](http://jsfiddle.net/fdvj9c1n/2/)
2. Proportional stretch to fill: `background-size: cover;`
   [Too tall div](http://jsfiddle.net/fdvj9c1n/3/)
   [Too wide div](http://jsfiddle.net/fdvj9c1n/4/)
3. Stretch to fill 100%: `background-size: 100% 100%;`
   [Too tall div](http://jsfiddle.net/fdvj9c1n/5/)
   [Too wide div](http://jsfiddle.net/fdvj9c1n/6/)

Comment: He wants a solution for img tag not background image.

Comment: @neaumusic, here's your jsfiddle example using background image https://jsfiddle.net/redwood646/df2hLc6v/1/

Answer (score 2):

use single css background shorthand property

```
.myDiv
{
  height: 400px;/*whatever you want*/
  width: 300px;/*whatever you want*/
  background: url('image-url.png') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: contain;
}

<div class="myDiv">
</div>
```

Comment: This is a good solution if the OP can get away with minor adjustments to the html, unless IE8 has to be supported (IE8 doesn't do `background-size`)

Answer (score 1):

A while back I found a jQuery solution called "backstretch".  Now this looks possible with CSS3:

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer. Now works as intended.

```js
var toggle = false,
    containerElement = document.querySelector("#container");
window.onclick = function () {
    containerElement.className = (toggle = !toggle ? "skinny" : "");
}
window.alert("click anywhere to toggle shapes. img is a large square");
```

```css
#container {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    transition: all .5s;
    margin: 0 auto; /* this is just for demonstration purposes */
}
#container.skinny {
    width: 200px;
    height:600px;
}
#img {
    height: auto;
    left: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* changed to 2d translate */
    width: 100%; /* full width in wide mode */
}

#container.skinny #img {
    width: auto; /* width reset in tall mode */
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <img id="img" src="http://farm8.static.flickr.com/7440/12125795393_3beca9c24d.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: @Neaumusic - I updated this answer and removed the absolute positioning requirements. It also now correctly shrinks the image width properly in wide mode.

Answer (score 0):

http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/CSS-Challenge-1-expand-and-center-image-fill-div

contained AND centered

I think this is the rendering you're trying to get, this might help ;)

https://jsfiddle.net/erq1otL4/

```
<div id="container" style="background-image: url(http://farm8.static.flickr.com/7440/12125795393_3beca9c24d.jpg);"></div>   

#container.skinny {
width: 400px;
height:600px;
}
#container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color:pink;
    background-position: center center;
}

var toggle = false,
containerElement = document.querySelector("#container");
window.onclick = function () {
    containerElement.className = (toggle = !toggle ? "skinny" : "");
}
window.alert("click anywhere to toggle shapes. img is a large square");
```

Answer (score -1):

Usually to achieve that you need to use:

```
parentdiv img {
   width:100%;
   height:auto;}
```

in order to make your image resize with the parent div.

This can cause some cropping issues (visually) if you set the overflow to hidden.

Comment: this doesnt work, width needs to be at least 100%, height needs to be at least 100%

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<div class="img_container">
   <img src="image/yourimage.jpg" alt="" />
</div>

<style type="text/css">
   .img_container{
      width: 400px;
      height: 400px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
   .img_container img{
       width: 100%;
       height: auto;
     }
 </style>
```

setting the height or the with auto will not make the image look stretched.

Comment: if height is less than width, this will not fill the entire surface

Comment: Match the height of the image to the container instead.

Comment: please see the revised question

Answer (score -1):

Use this class of Bootstrap .img-responsive   and if parent div changes add media Queries to image and div both

Answer (score -1):

Here is a very simple CSS solution that does not require changing the attributes of an img tag.

```
div{
            background-image: url("http://www.frikipedia.es/images/thumb/d/d5/Asdsa-asdas.jpg/300px-Asdsa-asdas.jpg");
            height: auto;
            width: 400px;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center;
        }
```